# Transport float with huge precision from Oracle to SQL Server via .Net and SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, odp.net, sqlbulkcopy

Working with ODP.Net I connect to Oracle database and transfer data to SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy.

As most of us already have noticed - Oracle float can hold values with precision higher than the .Net variables can hold.
.Net can hold precision up to 28 and Oracle can have e.g. 30.
In that case, the ODP.Net crashes with "Specified cast is invalid".

Oracle won't adjust their code and Microsoft won't create a new variable with higher precision, which leaves us to do workarounds.

In my case I couldn't find another way, but to convert the Oracle floats to nvarchar and then save them to SQL Server temp table that has a type nvarchar and then with a stored procedure to convert that nvarchar to SQL Server float.
Like that I can keep the original value and don't loose part of it's precision.

ORACLE:
For SqlBulkCopy I use this sql to get data from Oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(the_float) FROM the_table;

bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
```

Then on the SQL Server I see the value, like this:

```
-,00000000000000088817841970012
```

This is the default formatting that Oracle does (the leading 0 is missed).

Convert that using 
T-SQL

```
SELECT Try_convert(float,'-,00000000000000088817841970012') FloatValue
```

(I had to replace the , with . so my SQL Server would recognize it as float and the convert works!)

```
Try_convert(float,REPLACE('-,00000000000000088817841970012', ',', '.'))  FloatValue
```

Is this the way to go around the Oracle Float and .Net variables ( ODP.Net and .Net ) inconsistency that I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of all tags you used, I know a little bit of Oracle. Perhaps you're missing the format mask with the `TO_CHAR` function. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table the_table (the_float number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into the_table values (-0.00000000000000088817841970012);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select to_char(the_float) your_result,
  2         to_char(the_float, '0D9999999999999999999999999999999999') my_result
  3  From the_table;

YOUR_RESULT                              MY_RESULT
---------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
-,00000000000000088817841970012          -0,0000000000000008881784197001200000

SQL>
```

See if it helps (hopefully, it does).

More about format models here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A

Comment: Thanks. Will that work if the float has bigger base (I mean if it is 567891234.123412341231234).

Comment: You're welcome. It would, if you adjust format mask.